# How NavBarPage works?

Tags: hyperlink, menu, navbars

I'm using a Module to create some Site Page to publish on my SharePoint 2013 site. This is the Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="PageLayouts" Url="Pages">
      <File Name="Default.aspx" Path="PageLayouts\Web_Layout_Default.aspx" Url="Default.aspx">
        <NavBarPage ID="1002" Name="Look! I'm Here!" Position="1002" />
      </File>
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

I know that if I use the NavBarPage tag in this way I will have this result:

[image: Result]

I've some question:

- How to put the link in the menu on the left?
- I saw that the Position property has the range 1001 - 2000. Is there any guide that tell me to what position of the page any integer matches?
- The ID property must be an integer. Has it some correlation with the Position value? ID and Position must be always the same? Any File tag in Elements.xml must have an unique ID for the NavBarPage ID?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is an extract of the book ["Building the SharePoint User Experience" by Bjorn Furuknap](https://books.google.it/books?id=DcAykAi-jKgC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=sharepoint%20multiple%20navbarpage%20elements&source=bl&ots=kAnrs-3Pln&sig=Wv1co9ERBkiwQgfcJECqyTW_fIw&hl=it&sa=X&ei=4MFxVcSXMomfygOA2IHQBA&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=sharepoint%20multiple%20navbarpage%20elements&f=false):

NavBarPage: the element has three attributes, ID, Name and Position. The MSDN states that ID refers to the ID of the page, but this is rubbish.
The **ID attribute** actually refers to the nav bars defined in the site definition, not the page. The top link nav bar has an ID attribute of 1002. The QuickLaunch menu has an ID attribute of 1003. If you create your own nav bar, then you add your own bar's ID attribute.

The **Position attribute** is simple in theory, but it doesn't quite work as expected, or at all. The MSDN states that Position is an ordering number that goes from 1000 (the first position; can also be substituted by `Start`) to 2000 (or `End`). [...] The `Position` attribute does not behave as you would expect. The `End` position refers to the last element at the time the NavBarPage element is created.

Hope this helps answering your questions.